# Procedural mesh generation: cylinder and sphere

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, procedural-generation, procedural-programming

I need an algorithm that generates meshes at run-time of cylinders and spheres (one for each of them). I've been searching but I can't seem to find one that supports what I need or that I can truly understand.

Mesh attributes:
- Vertices: Position, Normal and Texture Coordinates
- Indices

Cylinder arguments: Height, bottom radius, top radius, stacks (sections along height), slices (parts per section)
Sphere arguments: Height, bottom radius, top radius, stacks (sections along radius), slices (parts per section)

There's no need for Object Oriented Programming. An array of floats for each of the vertices attributes and an array of integers for the indices is sufficient.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am asking for 2 algorithms, not a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. I have done nothing to solve this problem because I'm new to this topic.

Comment: Texture coordinates are very much dependent on the format of your texture; for cylinder mapping that is easy enough because you only need three separate regions for the two circular facets and the curved surface; sphere mapping is more complex, because a sphere has intrinsic curvature, so it cannot be mapped precisely using a 2-D texture

Comment: You must show what you have tried, what problems you faced, not just what you need... Some googling: https://github.com/caosdoar/spheres